# Get data by position in custom adapter by onClickListener

Tags: android, android-fragments, onclicklistener, baseadapter, android-viewholder

look to my custom adapter that extends BaseAdapter:

```
public class DrawerAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

    static class ViewHolder{
        TextView        cat_Title;
        TextView        cat_Count;
    }

    private Activity                            mActivity;
    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>  mData;
    private static LayoutInflater               mInflater;
    private JsonArray Categories                = null;
    public JsonObject Cat_Items                 = null;

    private static String                       CATEGORY_NAME;
    private static String                       CATEGORY_CNT;
    private static String                       CATEGORY_ID;

    public DrawerAdapter(Activity a, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> d){
        mActivity   = a;
        mData       = d;
        mInflater   = (LayoutInflater) mActivity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mData.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View dView              = convertView;
        ViewHolder holder       = null;

        HashMap<String, String> dCategorise = new HashMap<String, String>();
        dCategorise             = mData.get(position);
        CATEGORY_NAME           = dCategorise.get("CATEGORY_NAME");
        CATEGORY_CNT            = dCategorise.get("CATEGORY_CNT");
        CATEGORY_ID             = dCategorise.get("CATEGORY_ID");


        if (convertView == null){
            dView               = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_drawer_list_row, null);
            holder              = new ViewHolder();

            holder.cat_Title    = (TextView) dView.findViewById(R.id.category_title);
            holder.cat_Count    = (TextView) dView.findViewById(R.id.category_counter);

            dView.setTag(holder);

        }else{
            holder = (ViewHolder) dView.getTag();
        }


        holder.cat_Title.setTag(position);
        holder.cat_Title.setTypeface(MyriadRegular);
        holder.cat_Title.setText(CATEGORY_NAME);

        holder.cat_Count.setTypeface(Yagut);
        holder.cat_Count.setText(CATEGORY_CNT);


        holder.cat_Title.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int pos         = (Integer) v.getTag();
                String cat_ID   = mData.get(pos).get(CATEGORY_ID);
            }
        });
        return dView;
    }

}
```

This is my custom adapter and I'm using of this in my navigation drawer. I want to get category id by clicking on category title and send that to the fragment and changes fragment data base on this.
But it's return null for cat_ID

Now my questions:
1.Why it return null?
2.Is it right way to getting category id for sending to fragment?

Comment: what is the result of the CATEGORY_ID             = dCategorise.get("CATEGORY_ID");?

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin excuse me, I'm confused about dCategorise ?!

Comment: is the result null?? for CATEGORY_ID ?? try to log.d it

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin Aha, No man, and exactly problem is there! I get the right result there like two other CATEGORY_NAME and CATEGORY_CNT, but i get null in onClick! :(

Comment: "and exactly problem is there"??? so its null??

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin No No man, i get result there, but problem is in onclick....there is I got null

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend directly add the `CATEGORY_ID` to the button's tag by the time you got it from your HashMap

**sample:**

change this:

```
holder.cat_Title.setTag(position);
```

to:

```
holder.cat_Title.setTag(CATEGORY_ID);
public void onClick(View v) {
            String cat_ID        = (String) v.getTag();
        }
```

Comment: Thanks man, that's work properly. Can I set more than one Tag to a holderView?

Comment: @MAY3AM you are welcome. :)) , nope just one object.

Answer (score 1):

`int pos = (Integer) v.getTag();` 
Are you sure this is right? `v.getTag()` will get a `ViewHolder`, you shouldn't convert it into a integer.

Comment: You know what, mData is an ArrayList and i need an integer to get result by position like this mData.get(int index).get(Object key). what can i do?

Comment: just use `String cat_ID   = mData.get(position).get(CATEGORY_ID);` is ok?

Comment: No, I can't use position there, I got non-final variable